# Проблема с Android sdk

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, mobile-development

Уже несколько раз устанавливал Android Studio, но не могу понять в чем проблема.
В окне, где должны быть обозначены компоненты [image] нет необходимого мне компонента Android SDK, по туториолам показывают таким образом: [image]
Я в этом нуб, прошу помочь

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит так, как будто у вас уже установлен **Android SDK**. Вы можете установить (доустановить) необходимые вам компоненты и после установки **Android Studio**. Зайдите в **File** -> **Settings** -> **Appearance & Behaviour** -> **System Settings** -> **Android SDK**, там выберите необходимые вам компоненты и нажмите **ОК** (студия может и сама выделить вам нужные компоненты, так что вам останется лишь нажать **ОК**):

[image: Картинка]

Далее просто следуйте инструкциям.

(Скриншот сделан в **Intellij IDEA**, в **Android Studio** аналогично. Просто нет его под рукой)

Answer (score 0):

Инсталятор `Android Studio` так же как и ранее предполагает установку\обновление `Android SDK`.

Но вот выбор целевой папки для установки `Android SDK` на начальном этапе был убран. Все туториалы которые я находил на просторах интернета используют еще старый интерфейс установщика `Android Studio`.

Выбрать собственную целевую папку можно в последующих шагах. Будьте внимательны и не пропустите следующий экран:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, нажав кнопку с тремя точками, указываем путь куда мы желаем установить `Android SDK`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*У меня, например,  под систему отведен SSD 128Гб, это конечно удобно, но все же места там осталось немного. Потому, я выбрал установку на более емкий HDD 500Гб. Потому путь у меня выглядит так `D:\android\Sdk`.*

**Важно!** Просто написать путь будет недостаточно. Нужно создать пустую папку с названием `Sdk`.

Далее жмем `Next` для продолжения установки.